# Routing view to another URL based on parameters

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple Flask app that contains a few basic views. One of these views is called result. What it does is grabs the URL parameters using GET, then does a bunch of operations using the parameters, and finally renders the template using `render_template()` and passes it the calculated values.

On rendering, the result URL looks something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/result?s=abcd&t=wxyz
```

What I want to do is instead of rendering the template under the result view, I'd like to redirect to a new view (let's call it final), passing the calculated values along with the redirect, and render the template from there. Why do all this? Because I'd like the final URL to look like this instead:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/final/abcd
```

I'm sorry if the title is a bit vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution that "abcd" in the final URL can be the actual result:

```
@app.route("/result")
def calculate_result():
    s, t = request.args.get("s"), request.args.get("t")
    # Calculate result with s and t
    return redirect(url_for(".display_results", result=result))

@app.route("/final/<result>")
def display_results(result):
    return render_template("results.html", result=result)
```

If it cannot be, then you can use [`session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#sessions) instead:

```
@app.route("/result")
def calculate_result():
    s, t = request.args.get("s"), request.args.get("t")
    # Calculate result with s and t
    session["result"] = result
    return redirect(url_for(".display_results", result=result))

@app.route("/final/abcd")
def display_results():
    result = session.get("result")
    return render_template("results.html", result=result)
```

Comment: I tried using the second method, to no avail. The URL is successfully shown, but the result (calculate_result() stores 3 variables, two of which are dicts) is somehow not carried over in the session. Furthermore, the template is rendered but not rendered. The page contains no CSS, and all of the passed variables are of type None.

Comment: @Cyph0n - have you set a [`SECRET_KEY`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.secret_key) in your code?  The session won't work if you don't have one set.